# Getting IConfiguration in own ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

Im making `fixture` to my `tests`.

In my `FixtureFactory` im making my own `ServiceCollection`:

```
    private static ServiceCollection CreateServiceCollection()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddScoped<IConfiguration>();
        services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
        services.AddDbContext<TaskManagerDbContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<TaskManagerDbContext>();

        return services;
    }
```

Then, im getting this `services` from `scope`:

```
    var services = CreateServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();

    var context = services.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TaskManagerDbContext>();
    var userManager = services.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var roleManager = services.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var signInManager = services.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var tokenService = services.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TokenService>();
```

The problem starts when i added `TokenService` to my `ServiceCollection`.

Constructor, of `TokenService` looks like this:

```
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
```

It works great when i launch my `Core` app, but wont work from `ServiceCollection` that i mentioned above.

In Tests, i started to get this error:

> Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ServicesFixture fixture)
>   ---- System.ArgumentException : Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration'.
>   ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ServicesFixture fixture

This error started to show when i added `services.AddScoped<IConfiguration>();` to my `ServiceCollection` and when i started to get required service `TokenService`.

My question is, how to register properly `Configuration` that im using in `Service`?

Im using `Configuration` to get items from `settings.json`.

**EDIT:**

My `fixture` and sample test class:

```
public class ServicesFixture
{
    public TaskManagerDbContext Context { get; private set; }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; private set; }

    public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; private set; }

    public TokenService TokenService { get; private set; }

    public ServicesFixture()
    {
        var servicesModel = ServicesFactory.CreateProperServices();

        this.Context = servicesModel.Context;
        this.UserManager = servicesModel.UserManager;
        this.RoleManager = servicesModel.RoleManager;
        this.SignInManager = servicesModel.SignInManager;
        this.TokenService = servicesModel.TokenService;
    }

    [CollectionDefinition("ServicesTestCollection")]
    public class QueryCollection : ICollectionFixture<ServicesFixture>
    {
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
[Collection("ServicesTestCollection")]
public class CreateProjectCommandTests
{
    private readonly TaskManagerDbContext context;

    public CreateProjectCommandTests(ServicesFixture fixture)
    {
        this.context = fixture.Context;
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

When i delete `AddScoped<IConfiguration>();` from my collection and run tests, i get this error:

> Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'TaskManager.Infrastructure.Implementations.TokenService' has been registered.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ServicesFixture fixture)
>   ---- System.InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'TaskManager.Infrastructure.Implementations.TokenService' has been registered.
>   ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ServicesFixture fixture

Comment: You added `IConfiguration` with no implmentation.

Comment: In `Startup.cs` Configuration is just injected. How to get implementation of `Configuration`?

Comment: In startup.cs the framework would have created an implementation behind the scenes and added it. You will have to do the same using `ConfigurationBuilder`

Comment: Would you be more specific or post answer if you knwo the solution please?

Comment: You could also just create a `Mock` for `IConfiguration` and use that instead. It's not like you actually need to create `IServicesCollection` for your unit tests.

Comment: What information you need? I just ended up with editing my post. My fixture works, but when i added `TokenService` it stopped (you see it in second edit). I belive it is because i had not registered `IConfiguration`, but i dont know how to use it properly

Comment: The on problem here is `IConfiguration`. I dont know how to inject it (with implementation) to my own `ServiceCollection`

Comment: @michasaucer will you be using an actual settings file for the fixture or will you be mocking the configuration?

Comment: I want to use existing settings file that im using in my `WebApi` project (in this case, default `appsettings.json`)

Comment: Or whatever, i can make another `settings.json` file and implement it on my `Configuration` in my own `ServiceCollection`. The `settings` file is not a problem tbh

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You added `IConfiguration` with no implementation.

In *startup.cs* the framework would have created an implementation behind the scenes and added it. You will have to do the same using `ConfigurationBuilder`

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    //.SetBasePath("path here") //<--You would need to set the path
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"); //or what ever file you have the settings

IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();

services.AddScoped<IConfiguration>(_ => configuration);

//...
```

Comment: It works fine! Thanks!

Could you tell me, what will be better solution in testing enviroment? get `settings` from `Api.csproj` or make another, same `settings` file in `Tests.csproj`?

Comment: Have one settings file and let the test copy it to use for test. that way any changes to main settings will be moved over to test as needed.

Comment: Very helpful, I ran into a similar problem calling this from one of my classes: `var configuration = new ServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();` and it was returning `null` in the constructor of the class.  I replaced it with the first two parts of your code and it works fine.

Comment: Nice answer! Any particular reason to be services.AddScoped() instead of services.AddSingleton() ?

Comment: @VasilPopov My thinking was to make it scoped in case configuration changed between requests the ability is there to reload if needed though the feature is somewhat built into the configuration setting. For isolated tests singletons will work fine as well. Just a matter of preference

Comment: To make it work as scoped, shouldn't the Build part of ConfigurationBuilder be inside the lambda expression? Otherwise how the services know how to generate other instance for a different scope?